# How do I specify error member key in ASP.NET MVC CustomValidation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to add CustomValidation and make it return error for

**Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SubleaseCompany)**

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(CreateSpaceModelValidation), "ValidateCreateSpaceModel")]
public class CreateSpaceModel
{
    public Building Building { get; set; }
    public Space Space { get; set; }

    public string SubleaseCompany { get; set; }
}

public class CreateSpaceModelValidation
{
    public static ValidationResult ValidateCreateSpaceModel(CreateSpaceModel model)
    {
        return new ValidationResult("You should specify Sublease Contact", new[] { "SubleaseCompany" }).;
    }
}
```

I'm using second argument for ValidationResult constructor (memberNames) but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What route did you end up taking on this?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the MVC team never implemented the functionality for the MemberNames parameter.
See the following exert from.... http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

> In some situations, you might be
>   tempted to use the second constructor
>   overload of ValidationResult that
>   takes in an IEnumerable of
>   member names. For example, you may
>   decide that you want to display the
>   error message on both fields being
>   compared, so you change the code to
>   this:
>
> ```
> return new ValidationResult(
>     FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName),
> ```
>
> new[] { validationContext.MemberName,
>   OtherProperty });
>
> If you run your code, you will find
>   absolutely no difference. This is
>   because although this overload is
>   present and presumably used elsewhere
>   in the .NET framework, the MVC
>   framework completely ignores
>   ValidationResult.MemberNames.